# Is it possible to flip and rotate image using XSL?

Tags: xml, xsl-fo

I would like to take the image name  from a XML file and have it displayed flipped both horizontally (mirror image) and vertically (as a column) when viewed through a stylesheet.

Is it possible to do using XSL ?

Comment: @user522972: XSLT is about transformations from one XML vocabulary to another XML vocabulary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your transformations are done in a non-XSLT language I would use SVG within XSL-FO. This has support for multidirectional text.